# List cities where more than half of the students accepted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

tbl1: schoolID schoolname

tbl2 StudentID, schoolID ,Stu_Name, address, city, state, status

Status field contains value A for acceptance or R for rejected

I need to list cities in NY state where more than half of student applications were accepted.

Comment: Please try it yourself. If you face any trouble, ask a question with specific problem.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a homework writing service.

Comment: This is not a homework! I am working on a student applicant application! Thank you. I am asking a question because I am not familiar with such type of query writing.

Comment: You should still make an attempt to write this first, and if you have specific issues, post them here and we can help you fix the errors. Even though it's a fairly short request, you are still basically saying "please write this code for me" - that's not what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: I was thinking since you need more than half, I need to find max of counts /2 and based on that find the cities...

Comment: select city, max(count(studentid)) /2 
from 
where 
state =NY
and status = 'A"

Comment: You can't have an aggregate inside an aggregate. MAX is not going to help you here. How would you know if exactly half of the state has a status of 'A'? Don't think about the query syntax, think about how this would be done logically. Your count of studentid divided by 2 is a great start. There is another piece of the puzzle there though.

Comment: That is why I needed some help because I can think of how to count more than half but not sure how you would know which ones have more than half of Status = A

Comment: Why do you need to count more than half? Wouldn't half of the count be count(*) / 2?

Answer (score 1):

**SAMPLE TABLES**

```
SELECT * INTO #tbl1 FROM
(
   SELECT 1 schoolID,'SchoolA' schoolname
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,'SchoolB'
)TAB 


SELECT * INTO #tbl2 FROM
(
   SELECT 1 StudentID,1 schoolID ,'A' Stu_Name,'XXX' address,'CITYA' [CITY],'NY' [STATE],'A' [STATUS]
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2,1,'A','XXX','CITYA','NY','A'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 3,1,'A','XXX','CITYA','NY','A'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 4,1,'A','XXX','CITYA','NY','A'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 14,1,'A','XXX','CITYA','NY','R'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 5,1,'A','XXX','CITYA','NY','R'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 6,1,'A','XXX','CITYA','NY','R'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 7,1,'A','XXX','CITYB','NY','A'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 8,1,'A','XXX','CITYB','NY','A'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 9,1,'A','XXX','CITYC','NY','A'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 10,1,'A','XXX','CITYC','NY','R'
)TAB
```

**QUERY**

If you need to find out the cities where more than half of student applications were accepted irrespective of school, you can follow the below query.

```
DECLARE @CITY VARCHAR(30)='NY'

SELECT [CITY]
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [CITY]
    ,CASE WHEN 
    (
       -- Gets half of total count
       COUNT([STATUS]) OVER(PARTITION BY [CITY])/2) 
       >= 
       -- Checks if half of total count is greater than count of accepted for each cities
       COUNT(CASE WHEN [STATUS]='A' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY [CITY]
    ) 
    THEN 'N' 
    ELSE 'Y' 
    END ACCEPTED
    FROM #tbl2
    WHERE [CITY] = @CITY
)TAB
WHERE ACCEPTED='Y'
```

If you wan tot filter this condition by school, you can follow the below query

```
DECLARE @SCHOOLID INT = 1
DECLARE @CITY VARCHAR(30)='NY'

SELECT [CITY]
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [CITY]
    ,CASE WHEN 
    (
       COUNT([STATUS]) OVER(PARTITION BY [CITY])/2) 
       >= 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN [STATUS]='A' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY [CITY]
    ) 
    THEN 'N' 
    ELSE 'Y' 
    END ACCEPTED
    FROM #tbl1 T1
    JOIN #tbl2 T2 ON T1.schoolID=T2.schoolID AND T1.schoolID=@SCHOOLID
    WHERE [CITY] = @CITY 
)TAB
WHERE ACCEPTED='Y'
```

Comment: Thank you Sarath, how you filter by state 'NY'?

Comment: Also I see you are saying case when condition then N, shouldn't be case condition True then Y else N? Thanks.

Comment: This looks pretty good to me. The only thing I would change is to use a sum with a case expression instead of count(case when status='a'...it does the same thing but I think it is more clear to have sum(case when status='a' then 1 else 0 end).

Comment: I have updated the query to filter city by NY. And about the Y and N condition - that's the logic. That will work :) @user3267270